# Which version of WindowsAzure.Storage should I use?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blob, azure-storage

Which version of WindowsAzure.Storage should I use?
https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/

I have following environment

*- Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 Version 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL 

- Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.5.50709 

- Windows 7 Ultimate*

I need to work on blob service and table service

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not sure just run Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage in the Package Manager console, it will install the latest stable version by default.

The version you pointed (5.0.0) is the latest stable, so you'd be fine.

For more information see [the azure storage SDK page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net).